# How to dynamically import module which contains relative import to submodule?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

Folder structure:

```
foo/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        aworker1.py
        bworker2.py
        cworker3.py
        dworker4.py
        common/
            __init__.py
            entity_patterns.py
```

Each `worker*.py` file implements a class named 'Serializer_*'. Given a string, for example, 'Serializer_MP3', I'm need to find which file in `foo/foo/` implements that class, in order to extract `descriptor_pattern` class variable from it. So, I wrote foo/foo/worker_matcher.py with the function below:

```
def find_candidate(the_class):
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    files = glob(os.path.join(current_dir, '*worker*.py'))

    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]

        the_module = importlib.import_module(f'foo.{filename}')

        kls = next(
            (
                kls
                for kls
                in dir(the_module)
                if kls.startswith('Serializer_') and not kls.endswith('NOT_THIS')  # noqa
            ),
            None
        )

        if kls == the_class:
            return __import__(the_class.__name__, fromlist=[kls])
```

I can list all worker files, but I'm getting the `ModuleNotFoundError` when the loop reaches `cworker3.py` which have `from common import entity_patterns as ep`.

I know I can fix all imports in worker files to be absolute (like `from foo.common import entity_patterns as ep`), but as I have a lot of workers in production, it's simply not feasible. So, I'm looking for ways to overcome relative imports like that when dynamically searching for a class. Is it possible? How I can do that without rewriting every relative import in my workers?

My `PYTHONPATH` is `/home/caioignm/dev/foo`